# Applescript to Unmount Volumes Matching a Pattern

Tags: applescript, storage, mount

I have several backup offline and bootable backup volumes on a disk , and I would like to unmount all of them at startup. They all start with the name "Backup"

I've found the following Applescript courtesy of https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5102909, which is very efficient, but would appreciate help to add in wildcards. I would like it to unmount any volumes that being with "Backup"

```
set volname to "Backup" -- # name of target volume  

set p to (POSIX path of (volname & ":" as alias))'s text 1 thru -2

set sh to "diskutil umount " & quoted form of p & " &> /dev/null &"

do shell script sh
```

I feel like it should be possible, but always get messed up with the correct syntax. Your wisdom would be very appreciated!

*** Edit
My disk & volume structure looks like this:

```
disk2s1 EFI
disk2s2 Backup System 10May19
disk2s3 Backup Archives
```

I unmount the volumes at startup, so the disk can spin down. Chronosync automatically mounts/unmounts as needed during backup operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it... The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will unmount any mounted *disk* that starts with "Backup":

```applescript
set listOfDisks to list disks
set listOfDisksToUnmount to {}

repeat with thisDisk in listOfDisks
    if thisDisk starts with "Backup" then
        copy contents of thisDisk to end of listOfDisksToUnmount
    end if
end repeat

if listOfDisksToUnmount is not {} then
    repeat with thisDisk in listOfDisksToUnmount
        do shell script "diskutil unmount /Volumes/" & thisDisk's quoted form
    end repeat
end if
```

Note: If you have an issue with the `unmount` *verb* with `diskutil`, try `unmountDisk` instead.

Note: `contents` in `copy contents of thisDisk to end of listOfDisksToUnmount` doesn't copy the contents of the *disk*, it copies the *contents* of the *list item*, which is the *name* of the *disk*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! That worked without issue. My disk & volume structure looks like this:

Comment: Thanks, I know :) Just marked it.
I could follow the code. I just get so mixed up with the syntax, when I have to learn a little bits of VB, Applescript, POSIX, HTML, and I am not a programmer.
I used unmount for now, but will see if eject works instead. It would have an advantage of getting rid of all the backup partitions at once, but I suspect that once the disk is fully ejected, Chronosync won't be able to auto-mount anymore. So probably will stick with the diskutil unmount variation.   

I also added some details in the original post.

Comment: @user840, Yes, under that expressed circumstance, do use the the `do shell script "diskutil ..."` as it will still be able to be re-mounted.

Comment: @Goatmonger, I've updated my answer to reflect just unmounting, no ejecting. You can always look at the edit history if you want to see the original answer.